# matplotlib toolbar with control of marker options etc?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm 100% certain that I have, in the past, seen a matplotlib toolbar with a button which brought up a dialogue allowing the marker styles, line colours etc for the plot to be changed interactively.

This seemed really useful but it's definitely not in the current standard toolbar as documented [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html) and I cannot remember what I was using at the time!

Does anyone have any ideas?!

thanks

Comment: And you're certain it was matplotlib and not matlab?

Comment: Definitely not matlab.  I thought it might have been one of the "clones" like pythonxy or Spyder but I've looked at those and it doesn't /look/ as though it was, at least at current versions.

Comment: it is an extension to spyder I think, can't remember if it is installed by default, I think in python xy you are asked at installation time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bmu says, it is possible in [Spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) (and as far as I know it is so by default). There is an extra button on the toolbar (a green check), as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!  Not sure how I missed that but it was exactly what I was thinking of

Answer (score 0):

This option must be somewhere in matplotlib. When I do a GUI with matplotlib widget with toolbar, the button for the "figure options" is available. If I just use the plot command, the button is missing. 
Edit:
I found http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/How-to-modify-the-navigation-toolbar-easily-in-a-matplotlib-figure-window-td39172.html . If you change your backend in matplotlibrc to Qt4Agg ("backend      : Qt4Agg")  the button is shown.